# Is it possible to delete entries directly from the 'All entries' listing in the control panel?

Tags: entries, control-panel, entry, deletion

I have a couple of Channels with news entries imported from different RSS feeds. A lot of these entries have a similar topic, so it would be very nice if these entries could be deleted from the 'All entries' listing in the control panel. That way, entries from different sections can be compared by title, and easily deleted.

This is possible when using the listing of a single Channel, but not the 'All entries' listing. Is this still possible somehow.

Combining the entries in a single Channel is not an option unfortunately due to different fields and needs per RSS feed.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible natively in Craft, but you might want to consider voting for [this feature request](http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/9787533-select-and-delete-multiple-entries), which is very similar.

In the meantime, you could write a [custom plugin](http://craftcms.com/docs/plugins) that provided its own entry index view and allowed you to delete entries any way you wished.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean 'not possible'.